# $k$-means clustering

Tags: r, matlab, k-means

I have two hundred $15 \times 15$ matrices containing correlation values between 15 nodes at 200 different time points. I want to cluster the 200 matrices using $k$-means clustering.

**Question:** Is there a way to do this, probably in Matlab or R?

**Update**: I was able to solve it in Matlab by unwrapping each $15 \times15$ matrix into vectors and applying `kmeans()`.

Comment: You may want to look at the `kmeans` function in `R`. Library for the package is `stats`.

Comment: MatLab also has kmeans.  I just googled "kmeans matlab" and found this: (http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html).  Did you do even the most basic web search on the topic?

Comment: I am aware of the kmeans in matlab. But the problem is that kmeans requires your input to be a matrix and not cell as was in my case.